# Which is the best button to use for "back" in a USSD menu system?

Tags: mobile, user-behavior, users

USSD is [Unstructured Supplementary Service Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data)

The options are `0`, `*`, and `#`

My requirement is when the user dials any USSD code like *123#, then on the user's mobile screen it will display `Menu` (which here I called Main Menu of service) whist has the following options:

1. To your main balance
2. To know you mobile number
3. To know 3G data offer
4. To know 4G data offer
5. To know 2G data offer
6. To know special offer

If the user presses 3 then next submenu is appears on user screen like

Choose one option

1. L ist item
2. Rechage with 256 to get 1 GB/30 day
3. Recharge with 145 to get 400 mb/15 days

`#` Go back to Main menu

So I need a suggestion as to which is the better option to use `0` or `*` or `#` to go back to main menu, if all are 3 available, which one is more appropriate as there are may be lots of submenus from where the back option is needed.

Comment: Arvind, I've heavily edited your question down to the essential information, and what is revealed is that you need to add more information. What are some potential reasons why any one button might be better than the others? Do the buttons have other conventional uses in the system? USSD seems like a niche area of knowledge, so if you want good advice, you'll need to add more context.

Comment: If I'm interpreting this right, your only inputs are 13456789*0#, all the buttons on the phone? And you can only display text on the screen? It's an interesting question but it does need more explanation.

Comment: Do those buttons have any other uses in the system?

Comment: @dennisless, they have but in current menu or sub menu, any above mention button not used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do follow the conventions.

I have heard this from many service providers voice answering machines:

**To go back to main manu, press 0.**

`#` is used after dailing the number.

**Please enter you pass-code and press `#`**

`*` is used for many messaging service like the one you mentioned in your question *123.